# CASE statement takes long

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance

I've added a CASE...WHEN statement in my SELECT query and it's causing the query to run 25 seconds longer

Any thoughts on why?

Here is the original query that takes about 7-8 seconds (i.e. Without the CASE statement)

NOTE: I've simplified the query by adding some hardcoded values so that the focus of the code is drawn to the troublesome points outlined above

```
select * from (
    select
        (row_number() over (
              order by b.BookTitle
            ))
        as RowNumber,
        b.*
    from
        Books b 
) as t1
where 
    RowNumber between 40 and 60
order by
    RowNumber
```

Now, here it is with the CASE statement (note: The case statement is used to determine how to order the results)

```
declare @SortByField nvarchar(255)
select @SortByField = NULL

select * from (
    select
        case @SortByField
          when 'Published' then 
            (row_number() over (
              order by b.PublishDate, b.BookTitle
            ))
          when 'Price' then 
            (row_number() over (
              order by b.RetailPrice, b.BookTitle
            ))
          when 'Author' then
            (row_number() over (
              order by b.AuthorName desc, b.BookTitle
            ))
          when 'Sold' then
            (row_number() over (
              order by b.ItemsSold desc, b.BookTitle
            ))
          else
            -- Notice in the first line of code for this snippet that @SortByField is
            -- set to NULL? So this condition should evaluate yet it still takes significantly longer
            (row_number() over (
              order by b.BookTitle
            ))
        end as RowNumber,
        b.*
    from
        Books b 
) as t1
where 
    RowNumber between 40 and 60
order by
    RowNumber
```

Comment: Generally when doing something like this (host variable controlling branching execution) you want dynamic SQL, which can often alleviate similar performance problems.

Answer (score 2):

Well, it has to run all the `row_numbers()`, and that apparently takes some time.  Try using this subquery instead:

```
from (select row_number() over (order by (case when @SortByField = 'Published' then PublishDate end),
                                         (case when @SortByField = 'Price' then Price end),
                                         (case when @SortByField = 'Author' then Author end),
                                         (case when @SortByField = 'Sold' then Sold end),
                                         BookTitle
                               ) as RowNumber,
             b.*
      from Books b 
     ) b
```

This may look like the same logic, but it only calls `row_number()` once -- and `row_number()` would normally be more expensive than the `case`, so only calling it once should be an improvement.

Comment: In the OP's code, does the row_number() really run multiple times? I would have thought only the row_number() in the selected branch would run.

Comment: @JohnSaunders . . . I'm pretty sure all the `row_number()` would be called.  This is a function that is called once for the result set, not once per row, so it would have to be a very sophisticated optimizer to figure out that it is never needed.  This is analogous to aggregation functions that are processed for all branches of a `case`, even though only one returns a value.

Answer (score 1):

The first query may use an Index on the BookTitle column so the data is already in order.
But what's with the second query?

I think it first has to evaluate the case block for all the rows and then do the ordering.
Did you check the execution plan?

I would try to build the sql-statement in the procedure dynamically based on the given parameter @SortByField and then execute it with sp_executesql. So every input-parameter gets it's own execution plan instead of just one for the whole procedure. And every execution uses the right indexes.